# How to write dependent queries in MULE CE?

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component

I hear that we con't write two Inbound-endpoints in one flow, but below is my requirement, Second select query needs first query payload value. When I run this giving an exception. Please let me know if there is any alternate way to write this.

---

```
<flow name="Some">
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="SelectSome"
connector-ref="ProConnector" doc:name="SomeFromPro"

pollingFrequency="10000" queryTimeout="-1">
<jdbc:transaction action="NONE" timeout="10" />
<jdbc:query key="SelectSome"
value="SELECT top 1 * from table1 where IsProcessed = 0" />
<jdbc:query key="SelectSome.ack"
value="update table1 set IsProcessed=1 where ID = #[map-payload:ID] " />
</jdbc:inbound-endpoint>    
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="SelectSomeBR"
connector-ref="ProConnector" doc:name="SomeBRFromPro"
pollingFrequency="1000" queryTimeout="-1">
<jdbc:transaction action="NONE" timeout="10" />
<jdbc:query key="SelectSomeBR"
    value="SELECT * from table2 where IsProcessed = 0 and ParentID = #[map-payload:ID]" />
<jdbc:query key="SelectSomeBR.ack"
value="update table2 set IsProcessed=1 where ParentID = #[map-payload:ID] " />
</jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
.
.
.
.
</flow>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an *outbound* select query for your second query, like:

```
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="SelectSomeBR"
  connector-ref="ProConnector" doc:name="SomeBRFromPro"
  pollingFrequency="1000" queryTimeout="-1"
  exchange-pattern="request-response">
  <jdbc:transaction action="NONE" timeout="10" />
  <jdbc:query key="SelectSomeBR"
    value="SELECT * from table2 where IsProcessed = 0 and ParentID = #[map-payload:ID]" />
  <jdbc:query key="SelectSomeBR.ack"
value="update table2 set IsProcessed=1 where ParentID = #[map-payload:ID] " />
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

Reference: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-OutboundSELECTQueries

PS. This old expression syntax is obsolete: `#[map-payload:ID]` Use MEL instead: `#[message.payload.ID]"` (assuming the message payload is a map with a key named `ID`).

Comment: Thank you for response. Here It is leading me to add two outbound-endpoint statements. I meant I already have one insert outbound-statement running. Can we write two outbound-endpoints?

Comment: That works fine. But after it's not able to access #[map-payload:ID] OR #[message.payload.ID] value. Can you please let me know how to map the message payload with a key named ID.

Comment: The payload after a JDBC select endpoint is a List of Maps, so if you want the value of the `ID` column for the first row, use `#[message.payload[0].ID]`

Comment: It is running but I am not able to confirm that the outbound select query is selecting the values because ack query is not running and not able to access outbound-select statement payload.

Comment: Can we write sub flow here if yes, Could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Please open a new question and explain what you want to do with sub flows, what you've tried, etc... Comments are not the place for follow ups.